# Perl: Basic foreach logic with integers

Tags: perl, foreach

In the following code, I am attempting to write a very simple foreach math calculation loop.

```
use strict;  
use warnings;     
my @array = (1..10);  
my $sum = 0;  
foreach my $number (@array) {  
    $sum = $number / 2;  
}  
print "$sum\n"
```

In my head, the foreach loop should be going through each $number (1-10) in the @array calculating each number divided by 2. I was hoping it would print the answers out via $sum for each number 1-10, but instead I am getting the answer 5.

What's wrong with my logic?

Comment: It does what you describe ... and every time through it _assigns_ to `$sum`. So in the end you have `10/2` there, from the last iteration. If you mean to sum them up (by calling the variable `$sum`) then you need `$sum = $sum + $number/2`, or `$sum += $number/2`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the friendly reply.  I am now getting the answer 27.5 utlizing $sum += $number/2.  That ads them all up and divides by 2.  However, this is till not what I am looking for (unless I am doing something wrong still).  What I was hoping the foreach loop would do is divided each number by 2 and give me the results. For example: LOOP1 calculates 2/1  LOOP2 2/2, LOOP3 3/2, and so on. $sum would contain the answers for each calculation and print them.  Am I making sense?

Comment: You could either move the print statement into the loop,
or push the sum into another array @sums. (`push @sums, $sum;`)
You can then display the contents of that array using, for example `print join(",",@sums);`

Comment: You got the answer -- please also note that these are things you want to write in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move the print statement inside the foreach loop so that it prints out the current value of `$sum` each time through the loop :

```
use strict;  
use warnings;     
my @array = (1..10);  
my $sum = 0;  
foreach my $number (@array) {  
  $sum = $number / 2; 
  print "$sum\n"; 
}
```

That will output:

```
0.5
1
1.5
2
2.5
3
3.5
4
4.5
5
```

You could simplify your program quite a bit with something like:

```
use strict;  
use warnings;
foreach my $number (1..10) {
  print $number/2 , "\n";
}
```